# Swing: How to create a custom JToolTip like widget that moves with the mouse

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Java Swing question.

I have a `JPanel` which displays a graph. When I move the mouse over this graph, I want certain information to be displayed on a tooltip-like widget that moves with the mouse. How can I best implement this?

I guess my problem will be solved if I know how to position a custom `JComponent` absolutely within the `JPanel` that acts as my drawing canvas. I could then trap the mouse moved event and reposition/update the widget. Any other solution (including possibly using `JToolTip` directly) would also be very much welcome!

Comment: that isn't easy job, all examples that I saw were too long and based on JComponent's Model + SwingUtilities + JWindow, maybe someone have easies idea

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override the `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method to dynamically set the tool tip based on the mouse location.

Edit:

If you want the tooltip to continually move with the mouse then you will also need to override the `getToolTipLocation()` method.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ToolTipPanel extends JPanel
{
    public ToolTipPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 200) );
        setToolTipText("");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( Color.red );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
        g.setColor( Color.blue );
        g.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 200);
    }

    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getX() < 100)
            return "red";
        else
            return "blue";
    }

    public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        p.y += 15;
        return p;
//      return super.getToolTipLocation(e);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().add( new ToolTipPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe but I never saw tooltip flying/follows mouse on the screen and with connection to the JComponent under the mouse Cursor +1

Comment: thanks very nice example, then which of ways would be better option 1) to check JComponent by using SwingUtilities, then change tooltip properties from some pre-prepared Array 2) set tooltip only for expected JComponent directly and in this case JComponet returns properties back to the tooltip

Comment: If you are adding components to the panel then you would add a tooltip to each component. If you are painting images then you would need to track the shape of each image and iterate through all the shapes to determine where the mouse point is and then set the appropriate tool tip for the image.

Comment: Many thanks. I want the user to be able to set the tooltip to be visible or not. Is there a way I can control when the tooltip will be displayed?