# How to hide a popup window after some seconds if the cursor exits

Tags: java, swing, timer, cursor, hide

I have a `JDialog` as a Popup which shows up for 3 seconds and dispose.
It comes up at cursor position and has to dispose only if the cursor exits the popup.

If the cursor entered the Popup the timer stops and start again on exit.

But my first idea with a *dispose-*`Timer` that starts and stops via `MouseListener` doesn't work with some `JComponent`s, which causes a `mouseExited()`.

My second idea will never start the Timer

```
public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
    if(!Popup.this.getBounds().contains( e.getLocationOnScreen() )){
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

I don't want to add the Listener to every component in the popup.
Is there an easy way to do that.

Example:

```
public class Popup extends JDialog {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1337L;

    private final Timer timer = new Timer( 3000, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
            Popup.this.dispose();
            System.exit( 0 );
        }
    });

    public Popup() {
        setBounds( 100, 100, 300, 300 );
        addMouseListener( new PopupBehavior() );
        getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        getContentPane().add( new JTextArea(), BorderLayout.NORTH );
        getContentPane().add( new JSplitPane(0,new JPanel(), new JLabel("2")), BorderLayout.CENTER );
        getContentPane().add( new JProgressBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        getContentPane().add( new JLabel("west"), BorderLayout.WEST );
        getContentPane().add( new JSpinner(), BorderLayout.EAST );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Popup().setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }

    private class PopupBehavior extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
            System.out.println("mouseEntered");
            timer.stop();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e ) {
            System.out.println("mouseExited");
            timer.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495769/how-to-get-all-elements-inside-a-jframe/6495800#6495800).

Comment: @trashgod - you aren't suggesting to recursively register a listener with every child, are you?

Comment: Only as a last resort if `JSpinner` is actually involved; the `AWTEventListener` you cited looks more promising.

Comment: @trashgod agreed on last resort :-) Might be necessary in sandboxed contexts, f.i., which dont permit the register an AWTEventListener. Which is used by the JLayer as well, but being core as a priviledged action

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of jdk7 you can decorate your container with a JLayer and stop/start the timer in its processMouseEvent

```
class DisposingLayerUI extends LayerUI {

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        super.installUI(c);
        JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
        jlayer.setLayerEventMask(
                AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK 
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        JLayer jlayer = (JLayer)c;
        jlayer.setLayerEventMask(0);
        super.uninstallUI(c);
    }


    @Override
    protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e, JLayer l) {
        if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED) {
            timer.stop();
        } else if (e.getID() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED){
            timer.start();

        }
    }

}

// to use in your code, do all init and then decorate the contentPane
...
setContentPane(new JLayer(getContentPane(), new DisposingLayerUI()));
```

For older versions, you can use the layer from the [JXLayer](http://jxlayer.java.net) project (it's were the current was developed) or go for a manually implements global listener, as f.i. shown in [Global Event Listeners](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/08/30/global-event-listeners/)

Answer (score 2):

just for example [JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124) (and as I know majorities of `JComponents`) has `Model`

if you'll start `javax.swing.Timer` from Model or from mousemoved out from pre-defined `Rectangle`

if mouse returns back to the pre-defined `Rectangle`  then just restart `javax.swing.Timer`

excelent sugestion since about JToolTip [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138914/swing-how-to-create-a-custom-jtooltip-like-widget-that-moves-with-the-mouse/7139057#comment-8561297)

Comment: more random thoughts, this time unrelated to receiving mouse events for children ;-)