# How to only display tooltips for icon of JTree - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

For my `JTree` I have a custom `DefaultTreeCellRenderer` which overrides the `getTreeCellRendererComponent` method. This allows me to define custom icons for the tree nodes.  If I call `setToolTipText` in my renderer, the tooltip gets displayed even if you just hover over the text. So my question is:
How can I make it so that the tooltip only gets displayed when you hover over the icon of the node.

Comment: Maybe override the `getToolTipText(...)` method to set the tool tip only when the mouse is over the Icon. Here is a basic example overriding this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138914/swing-how-to-create-a-custom-jtooltip-like-widget-that-moves-with-the-mouse/7139057#7139057

Comment: @camickr Thats an interesting approach I haven't yet considered. I'll certainly try it.