# ToolTip for components that are not JComponent (Ellipse)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tooltip

I have a program that draws coordinates to a screen. I need to add functionality that displays a tooltip with its location when hovering over each point. However, I can't get it to work properly and I'm not sure why.

Coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinate extends Ellipse2D.Double {
    private Point point;
    private String name;
    private int radius;

    public Coordinate(Point point, String name, int radius) {
        super(point.getX(), point.getY(), radius, radius);
        this.point = point;
        this.name = name;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

Grid class:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        initOrigin();
        super.paintComponent(graphics);

        graphics.drawLine(0, getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight() / 2);

        // draw Y axis
        graphics.drawLine(getWidth() / 2, 0, getWidth() / 2, getHeight());
        if (coordinates != null) {
            drawCoordinates(graphics);
        }
    }

    protected void drawCoordinates(Graphics graphics) {
        System.out.println(coordinates.toString());
        for (int i = 0; i < this.coordinates.size(); i++) {
            int radius = coordinates.get(i).getRadius();
            int x = (int) Math.round(coordinates.get(i).getPoint().x * X_SCALING) + originX;
            int y = (int) Math.round(coordinates.get(i).getPoint().y * -1 * Y_SCALING) + originY; // flip bit to get vertical coordinates in proper place
            System.out.println(x);
            System.out.println(y);
            graphics.fillOval(x - radius, y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
            setToolTipText(coordinates.get(i).toString());

        }
    }

@Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
        for (Coordinate coordinate : coordinates) {
            if (coordinate.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                return coordinate.toString();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm setting the tooltip in the `drawCoordinates()` method and overriding the `getToolTip()` method as well but nothing is popping up. Obviously I'm missing something but I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Back in the day, I created an AreaManager. I think it would be worth your time to check out (https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/)

Comment: It doesn't have "tooltip" capabilities, but if you look at Buttonize, you should start to get ideas about how you could create a JLabel in the popup layer in a JLayeredPane (Instead of a JPanel)

Comment: @ControlAltDel Do you perhaps know of any components that I can use instead of an ellipse that has built-in tooltip functionality? It doesn't have to be an ellipse specifically; I was looking at ImageIcon but I don't think that has tooltip functionality either.

Comment: You definitely need to remove `setToolTipText` from your drawCoordinates method.  Never modify a component’s state while painting it.  Your `getToolTipText` implementation looks correct;  perhaps there is an issue with the Coordinate.contains method, or perhaps `initOrigin()` is applying a transformation that is causing the coordinates’ visible locations to differ from the x and y in the data?

Comment: Setting the tool tip text in the drawCoordinates() method doesn't help. This will always set the text to the last coordinate painted. You need to: 1) set the tool tip text to an empty value when the component is created to register tooltip processing for the component. 2) Override the `getToolTipLocation()` method to the placement of the tool top vollows the mouse. 3) Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138914/swing-how-to-create-a-custom-jtooltip-like-widget-that-moves-with-the-mouse/7139057#7139057 for a basic example to get you started.

Comment: *I can't get it to work properly* - define what that means when asking a question. We can't guess what behaviour you see. Tell us what happens and what you expect to happen. For example, to you ever see a tooltip? If so, does the text ever change?

Comment: @mgwqiwdd "... instead of an ellipse" There are plenty of components both in J2SE and on GitHub. The issue is that (J)Component is defined as being a rectangle (x,y,width,height) if you want non-rectangular components, you will need something like what I created